# Uncaught ReferenceError: value is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting an error of Uncaught ReferenceError while I want call a function. I want to pass some value through this function. Function declaration is another side.

Here is my jQuery code I populate data in a table from json data. Please note that in here username I have value like rifat and when I click or call onget(rifat) I got Uncaught ReferenceError: rifat is not defined

```
 for (let i = 0; i < result.data.resultSet.length; i++) {
        let tableallrowdata = {
            username: result.data.resultSet[i].username,
            firstname: result.data.resultSet[i].firstname,
            usertype: result.data.resultSet[i].usertype
        };

        console.log(tableallrowdata);

        let tableItem = "<tr><td>" + result.data.resultSet[i].username + "</td>";
        tableItem = tableItem + '<td>' + result.data.resultSet[i].firstname + '</td>';
        tableItem = tableItem + '<td>' + result.data.resultSet[i].lastname + '</td>';
        tableItem = tableItem + '<td>' + result.data.resultSet[i].email + '</td>';
        tableItem = tableItem + '<td>' + result.data.resultSet[i].usertype + '</td>';

        tableItem = tableItem + '<td ><a onClick="onGet(' + tableallrowdata.username + ', ' + tableallrowdata.firstname + ', ' + tableallrowdata.usertype + ')"><img src="/images/Common UI Assets/Icon-16.png" ></img></a><a><img  src="/images/Common UI Assets/Icon-16 _Delete.png" style="padding-left:20px;" /></a></td></tr>';


        newTableData += tableItem;

    }
```

And here the function body. I console it but before control goes here I got this error. Here is my code of the function

```
  this.onGet = function (username, firstname, usertype) {


    console.log(username);
    console.log(firstname);
    console.log(usertype);
    //var url = "./UserUpdate?name=" + username + "&firstname=" + firstname + "&usertype=" + usertype;
    //window.location.href = url;
}
```

I think got this because value is string. How can I solve this?

Comment: The error says "value is not defined" but none of the code you posted contains `value`? Please create a [mre]. (plus, your code doesn't have *any* jQuery in it, it's all vanilla JS)

Comment: onGet(' + tableallrowdata.username +  here suppose username Rifat i got rifat is not difined

Comment: The context of this code is unclear, I would suggest building it in a codepen or something and providing that.

Comment: Right, you aren't wrapping the parameters in quotes. Just one reason why inline code is bad.

Comment: can you help me or give me the code snipit how can i do it @Chris G

Comment: Just compose the URL in the for loop and set is as `href` for the link; you don't need that function at all.

Comment: I did this but I need to pass the value as querystring that way did not work . can you give me the code . It will be helpful

Comment: Here's actual jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/0g5kzadm/

Comment: Thanks It works and solved my problem many many thanks brother

Comment: please post your answer and i will vote